# Yii2 get value from Gridview button using javascript

Tags: javascript, yii2, jquery-ui-dialog

I am new to Yii2 Framework , I have developed a module that will upload and display file uploaded from server using Yii2 advance framework. I completed the function for uploading the file , However. In my other function that need to display the file like pdf file to jquery ui dialog.My problem is I cannot get the value of the button when I click the button to display the pdf file uploaded. Thank you guys in advanced.

```
// Here is Gridview code in Index where my button Exist.
 <?= DynaGrid::widget([
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        // 'ntraining_id',
        'ctraining_description',
        //'dtraining_datefrom',
         [
            'attribute'=>'dtraining_datefrom',
            'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_DATE,
            'format'=>'raw',
            'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd']
            ],
         ],
       // 'dtraining_dateto',
         [
         'attribute'=>'dtraining_dateto',
         'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_DATE,
         'format'=>'raw',
         'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
          'pluginOptions'=>['format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd']
         ],
         ],
        'ctraining_numberhours',
        'ctraining_type',
        'ctraining_conducted',
        //'ctraining_attachment',

        [
        'attribute'=>'ctraining_attachment',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'label' => 'View Profile',
        'value' => function ($model){

                    return  Html::a(Yii::t('app', ' {modelClass}', [
                    'modelClass' => $model->ntraining_id,
                    'header' => 'raw',

                    ]), ['TblTrainingController/Listeaffecter'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success opener', 'id'=>'opener', 'data' => $model->ntraining_id,]);   

            },
        ],

        //'id',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
        'storage'=>DynaGrid::TYPE_COOKIE,
        'theme'=>'panel-info',
        'gridOptions'=>[
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'id' => 'grid',
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'panel'=>['heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title">LEARNING AND DEVELOPMENT (L&D) INTERVENTIONS/TRAINING PROGRAMS ATTENDED</h3>'],
        ],
    'options'=>['id'=>'dynagrid-1'], // a unique identifier is important
]); ?>
```

Here is javascript Code

```
$this->registerJs("$(function(){

    $('.opener').click(function(e) {

            alert(e.data);
           //alert($(this).val());
            e.preventDefault();
            ViewPDfAttach();

    });
```

});");

[Here is the image of my interface that display null when I click the button from gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U6qK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to `alert(e.data);` means you want to get the value of variable `e` from function callback.

While calling `alert($(this).val());` means you want to get the value from `value` attribute in the element, but there's no `value` attribute found in yours.

Based on your element structure, if you want to get the value from `data` attribute, you can do this:

`alert($(this).attr('data'));`

If your element has structure like `<a data-hello="Hello there">Click me</a>`, you can alert with this one:

`alert($(this).data('hello'));`

See here for more informations:

- [JQuery `.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [JQuery `.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Yes.. Big Thanks to You sir @khotin . Now it works thanks :) God  Bless